# I can send Slack API to post just like share, but it's not working to show Pictures

Tags: bash, curl, jq, slack, slack-api

#### Ideal

I can send Slack API to post just like share, and ideal is to show pictures on it.

#### What I tried

```js
    const attachments = {
        "fallback": somePostData.text,
        "ts": pickedMessage.ts,
        "author_id": somePostData.user_id,
        "author_subname": somePostData.user_name,
        "channel_id": "---",
        "channel_name": "---",
        "is_msg_unfurl": true,
        "text": somePostData.text,
        "author_name": somePostData.user_name,
        "author_link": "---",
        "author_icon": somePostData.user_icon,
        "mrkdwn_in": ["text"],
        "color": "D0D0D0",
        // "files": somePostData.files,
        "from_url": somePostData.url,
        "is_share": true,
        "footer": "Posted in ----"
    }

    var param = {
        "response_type": "in_channel",
        "text": somePostData.url,
        "files": somePostData.files,
        "attachments": [ attachments ],
        "display_as_bot": false,
        "upload": true,
    }
    res.status(200).send(param);
```

I could post like share,  but it doesn't show pictures.
I made sure the response has valid format like

```
                    "files": [
                        {
                            "id": "---",
                            "created": 1576130341,
                            "timestamp": 1576130341,
                            "name": "---",
                            "title": "---",
                            "mimetype": "image\/jpeg",
                            "filetype": "jpg",
                            "pretty_type": "JPEG",
                            "user": "---",
                            "editable": false,
                            "size": 233329,
                            "mode": "hosted",
                            "is_external": false,
                            "external_type": "",
                            "is_public": true,
                            "public_url_shared": false,
                            "display_as_bot": false,
                            "username": "",
                            "url_private": "---",
                            "url_private_download": "---",
                            "thumb_64": "---",
                            "thumb_80": "---",
                            "thumb_360": "---",
                            "thumb_360_w": 360,
                            "thumb_360_h": 270,
                            "thumb_480": "---",
                            "thumb_480_w": 480,
                            "thumb_480_h": 360,
                            "thumb_160": "---",
                            "thumb_720": "---",
                            "thumb_720_w": 720,
                            "thumb_720_h": 540,
                            "thumb_800": "---",
                            "thumb_800_w": 800,
                            "thumb_800_h": 600,
                            "thumb_960": "---",
                            "thumb_960_w": 960,
                            "thumb_960_h": 720,
                            "thumb_1024": "---",
                            "thumb_1024_w": 1024,
                            "thumb_1024_h": 768,
                            "image_exif_rotation": 1,
                            "original_w": 1200,
                            "original_h": 900,
                            "thumb_tiny": "---",
                            "permalink": "---",
                            "permalink_public": "---",
                            "is_starred": false,
                            "has_rich_preview": false
                        }
                    ],
```

I put this to attachment block and top level.
but it never worked.

#### Conclusion

Any information is appreciated.

Comment: How does your input look? Or, is this a question about how to use the API?

Comment: Do you want to get posts, like in channels or just profiles of users?

Comment: @oguzismail Thank you. It's API question. I edited a lot